# ArcGIS Pro or Drone2map mosaic cleaning

Tags: arcgis-pro, pix4d, drone2map

I am looking for the best way in either Drone2map or ArcGIS orthoimagery tool to mask parts of individual photos from being projected onto the final mosaic ortho. Like moving traffic so we can use projection from image that doesn’t have the vehicle. Like how pix4d allows drawing mask and changing which image is used.